# Supressing Null in a Do-loop

Tags: export

I'm trying write a Do-loop that creates batch files that run .exe files with input parameters. I have to rename to *.bat since `Export` doesn't like outputting batch files. The output produces batch files with the text of the form:

```
Analyze.exe Calibration_# Null [input parameters]
```

which doesn't run due to the `Null`.

How would I go about suppressing the `Null` in this case?

I'd also like to change input parameters, but it seems that `Do` likes inserting `Null`. I've tried `DeleteCases Null`, but it's baked into the string, so that doesn't work.

```
Do[
  shotN = n;

  DeleteFile[{"1.bat", "2.bat"}];
  Export["1.txt", 
    StringReplace[
      "Analyze1.exe Calibration_xx [input parameters]",  
      "xx" -> ToString[shotN]]];

  Export["2.txt", 
    StringReplace[
     "Analyze2.exe Calibration_xx [input parameters]", 
     "xx" -> ToString[shotN]]];

 RenameFile["1.txt", "1.bat"];
 RenameFile["2.txt", "2.bat"];

 Run["1.bat"]
 Run["2.bat"]

 , {n, 1, 10}]
```

Comment: Try `Export["filename.bat", <<string>>, "Text"]`. That should get you rid of the need for `Rename`. And separate the `Run`s by semicoli (`;`).

Comment: That seemed to do the trick! Many thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The `Run`s need to be separated by semicoli. Moreover, you may use the export filter `"Text"` independent of the file type. This removes the need (i) to delete potentially preexistent files and (ii) to rename the files after export. Also `StringJoin` (`<>`) might become your friend.

```
Do[
 Export[
  "1.bat", 
  "Analyze1.exe Calibration_" <> ToString[n] <> " [input parameters]",
  "Text"];
 Export[
  "2.bat", 
  "Analyze2.exe Calibration_" <> ToString[n] <> " [input parameters]",
  "Text"];
 Run["1.bat"];
 Run["2.bat"];
 , {n, 1, 10}]
```